# Does undetected-chromedriver still work on windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, selenium, windows-7, pyinstaller

I'm writing a python for various people using selenium and undetected-chromedriver. I distributed it after compiling with pyinstaller. Win10 users have no complaints, but the one with Windows 7 is unable to open the final .exe, because windows says it's incompatible with his version and also 'api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dd' is missing. Does this mean Windows 7 is over and the program cannot be launched on Windows 7?

Comment: You need to target Windows 7. Maybe use older version of the compiler.

Comment: Note that Python 3.9.12 cannot be used on Windows 7 or earlier. [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/#:~:text=Note%20that%20Python%203.9.12,on%20Windows%207%20or%20earlier.&text=Note%20that%20Python%203.10.3,on%20Windows%207%20or%20earlier.)